# How do I use the same textfield to put text in two different text widgets?

Tags: flutter

I am doing a commentaries box for a network social app, like facebook or TikTok.
I need one `textfield` that can send text for two different `textWidgets` when i tap two different buttons, but with the same textField input. Anybody can help me with this?

For now I have only achieved to put text in the principal commentaries text widget when the user press on the button "comment" but I don’t know how to use that textfield input when other user wants to answer that comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `TextEditingController` to get updated text of `TextField` and use it with any text widget

```
 final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
```

and int `TextField` use `_controller`

```
TextFormField(
          controller: _controller,
         .......
        ),
```

to get value from `_controller`

```
Text(_controller.text)
```